Circular progress bar in iOS with alpha long progress
There are some ways for creating a circular progress bar in iOS (Example).

But I'd like to achieve an effect where the head of the progressbar is rounded and the progress alpha fades along the way. Something like this:

Any ideas how can achieve this kind of effects?

One approach is to mask a CAGradientLayer with a CAShapeLayer. The shape layer should have an arc as its path, and a lineCap of .round.
class FadingProgressView: UIView {
    let shapeLayer = CAShapeLayer()
    let gradientLayer = CAGradientLayer()
    
    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        backgroundColor = .clear
        layer.addSublayer(gradientLayer)
        gradientLayer.mask = shapeLayer
        gradientLayer.colors = [UIColor.blue.cgColor, UIColor.white.cgColor, UIColor.white.cgColor]
        gradientLayer.type = .conic
        gradientLayer.startPoint = CGPoint(x: 0.5, y: 0.5)
        gradientLayer.endPoint = CGPoint(x: 0.4, y: 0)
        gradientLayer.locations = [0, 0.75, 1]
        gradientLayer.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear.cgColor
        
        shapeLayer.fillColor = nil
        shapeLayer.strokeColor = CGColor(gray: 0, alpha: 1)
        shapeLayer.lineWidth = 5
        shapeLayer.lineCap = .round
        
        let animation = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "transform.rotation")
        animation.fromValue = CGFloat.pi * 2
        animation.toValue = 0
        animation.duration = 1
        animation.repeatCount = .greatestFiniteMagnitude
        layer.add(animation, forKey: "transform.rotation")
    }
    
    override func layoutSubviews() {
        super.layoutSubviews()
        gradientLayer.frame = bounds
        shapeLayer.frame = bounds
        let path = UIBezierPath(
            arcCenter: .init(x: bounds.midX, y: bounds.midY),
            radius: bounds.width / 2 - 20,
            startAngle: 1.55 * .pi, endAngle: .pi, clockwise: true)
        shapeLayer.path = path.cgPath
    }
    
    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }
}

Usage:
class MyViewController: UIViewController {
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        let progress = FadingProgressView(frame: CGRect(x: 200, y: 200, width: 100, height: 100))
        view.addSubview(progress)
    }
}

